# Not able to recognize two buttons on a lightbox using webdriver

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on `ChangePassword` or `Cancel` link on the below screenshot using Selenium webdriver. But webdriver is not recognizing. Once I enter text into old and new password, enter tab, text in red is generated. Not able to click cancel. All are in the same `iframe`.

The red text is populated after we fill the old and new password fields. Able to locate the text elements. (Change password and cancel are called through asynchronous function javascript or something like that, not sure about this).  As a side note, they are all in a light box.

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("abcContext");
    driver.switchTo().frame("abcApplication");
    getObject("ChangePassword").click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("abcContext");
    driver.switchTo().frame("abcApplication");
    driver.switchTo().frame("abcPasswordConfiguration");
    getObject("OldPassword").sendKeys("abcderf");
    getObject("NewPassword").sendKeys("%CAPITAL");
    getObject("ConfirmPassword").sendKeys("%CAPITAL");
    `<iframe id="abcPasswordConfiguration" class="LightboxIFrame" 
    frameborder="0"      scrolling="no" 
    src="abcPasswordConfiguration.htm" name="abcPasswordConfiguration" style="height: 
    262px; width: 590px; display: block;" ariahidden="false"> 
    !DOCTYPE html> <html class=" js no-flexbox flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext 
    no-webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb 
    hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs 
    backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity 
    cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections 
    csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video 
    audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg 
    smil svgclippaths">
    <head>
    <body style="padding:0px 10px" onload="setTimeout( init, 0 )">
    <form>
    <div class="section edit-section first-section">
    <div class="ft buttons" style="padding-left:10px">
    <span id="passwordSubmitButton" class="yui-primary-button yui-push-button">
    <a onclick="cancel(); return false;" href="#">Cancel</a>`
```

Thanks

Comment: What language is this? Is this Java? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes it is java..attached the html source to locate Cancel link

Comment: How to handle the buttons in javascript in webdriver?

Comment: I think they are called through asynchronous function using javascript or something like that, not sure about this

Comment: I'm guessing that your question is missing a tag for selenium webdriver or something like that. I've added the tag. This tool can sometimes be used with Java, but again, I don't really see any Java code in the code you've posted. If it's your code, you should know what kind of code it is. Does its file have a `.java` extension?

Comment: When i look at the page source i see .js for IFrameLightbox. Do you mean i am using java for webdriver or the application is using java? For both questions the answer is yes both are JAVA...for this particular functionality its javascript may be?

Comment: A `.js` file is a JavaScript file, which is a completely different programming language from Java.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to handle an element through javascript for webdriver?

Comment: Please reformat the code you posted. As it is, it is very difficult to read. Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve